# Infer the type value of a property based on the type value of another property in an array of object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this type

```js
interface Route {
    name: string,
    path: string
}

const routes = [
    {
        name: "first",
        path: "/first"
    },
    {
        name: "second",
        path: "/second"
    }
] as const
```

And I would like to create a function that would help me get a specific route path for the matching route.

```js
const to = <Routes extends ReadonlyArray<Route>, CurrentRoute extends Routes[number]>(routes: Routes, name: CurrentRoute["name"]): CurrentRoute["path"] => {
    // Implementation irrelevant here
    return "" as CurrentRoute["path"]
}

const path = to(routes, "first")
// Does not work, return a union instead of a string
```

I would like this function to return a single string that is infered from the matching object's name so that:

- `"/first"` is returned by TypeScript when calling this function with `"first"`
- `"/second"` is returned by TypeScript when calling this function with `"second"`
- ...

The implementation is irrelevant, I would like a TypeScript's type system's solution, the implementation is trivial.

[Link to reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCulkG8BQyRyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gDSHEAOcYAFtXQyEb4AvvnwJ0IOsihZINZAF5kAbTZECxLSXJVkAIhjAodfa20cuvAwHojJsPvXJh54pos6K1fTQgSQABMzZy1OHh8bPwDg51EAXWQ4BQC6MVSwZDB0JWQAHgxsCAUIAA9IIIVUCDhAyQAbAE8AQSgoOEaCuQgAPmZkAGFMNohwQpwyisCq7poVEEwyACNoeJ6AClkimmpx4v7Sb0HhqFGwPZV9Q4h9eIBKaiGRse7L8O5bpR68ZxsbZAAkmR2PUIBRwFxgJJkMZTqCAG5wcDIbjQCDOU5gYYgAz6JIKJ6nF5FN5WW4idKSaTvXLZTazfqGYymO5AA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version doesn't work because there is no inference site for the `CurrentRoute` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument.  For better or worse, generic types cannot be inferred from [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) like `CurrentRoute["name"]`; there was an old pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#20126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126) which would have done this, but it never made it into the language.

To make this work you should have the `name` property correspond directly to a generic type parameter (let's call it `N`), and then use that type to *compute* the type corresponding to your `CurrentRoute`.  Here's one way to do it:

```
const to = <R extends Route, N extends R["name"]>(
    routes: readonly R[], name: N): Extract<R, { name: N }>["path"] => {
    // Implementation irrelevant here
    return null!;
}
```

Because we don't care about the exact order of the elements of `routes` (at least not in your example), I have changed your `Routes` type parameter (corresponding to the entire array) to just `R` (corresponding to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of members of that array).  The `N` type parameter is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `R["name"]`, meaning the union of `name` property types in `R`.

And the return type takes `R` and [uses the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to extract the union member with a `name` property of type `N`, and then indexes into that to get the `path` property type.

Let's make sure it works:

```
const path = to(routes, "first");
// const path: "/first"


const path2 = to(routes, "second");
// const path2: "/second"
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCulkG8BQyRyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gDSHEAOcYAFtXQyEb4AvvnwJ0IOsihZINZAF5kAbTZECxLSXJVkAIhjAodfa20cuvAwHojJsPvXJh54pos6K1fTQgSQABMzZy1OHh8bPwDg51EAXWQ4BQC6MVSwZDB0JWQAHlRkCAAPSCCFDGwIZmQAOSLSiHK0FX1SCn14gD4ACmdZKppqKAg4QMkAGwBPFvia9r1agEpqAFFSqEQwAprcL0WXLtbw7k6lLrxnGxtkAEkydgmICnAuYElkYxGngDc4cGQ3GgEH6EDAmCgIBImAmEwAhABuETpSTSE65bI9AbyGqGYymJZI67IDLIE6ReymMTiVGZE4AJgx6CxcggNFx0UkwUJ+GJpIZkU5QSc+CAA)

Comment: Usng `Extract` works like a charm, thanks I'll take a look into the documentation for this utility type!