# Typescript: Infer the type of property based on value of another property

Tags: typescript

### Code

```
interface Order {
    customer: Customer,
    address: Address
}

interface Customer {
    name: string
}

interface Address {
    firstLine: string
}

interface OrderUpdateRequest {
    key: 'customer'|'address',
    value: Customer | Address
}

const myThing = {customer: {name: 'Bob'}, address: {firstLine: 'my street'}} as Order

const updateRequest = {key:'customer',  value: {name : 'Dave'}} as OrderUpdateRequest
myThing[updateRequest['key']] = updateRequest['value']
```

### Background

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8BQyRyCArgM5gD2AttAFzIDCF1dUANIcXACa9QI5cowCC-QcPwBffPlCRYiFC0q1oebkRBw6jSlGwy5C6PCTJxAoeU3FkMYFEoAZUBH1hDILMfngzZTRMHwBVAAdeOEgAJQgAR1IhMDtiAGsIAE9GAHIyNXYcgB8cvmthHK57ADc4ABskxlU2DSLLCRs-BCoQSmQaTIxsZABePHyWqEZcHT1kHIAjKgWc6Q5kMskRPEdnMDcQD3mB5AMICDBV6Q3bIZ85bt6U0kjoiDjE5NG8DOy81nUUEqRFqDSOM10KFyABE4NUIFcbsFsBEorEEklKPgBncsABtF5o94Y5J4nK-HIAXUp30Jbw%20mLAZNBSSpQA)

Using the playground above as an example, I want to be able to create a generic interface which would accept either `customer` or `address` as a key, and then if the key is `customer` for TS to know that the value would be an instance of `Customer`.

### Current problem

I cannot change the value of the `customer` on the order because TypeScript expects the `value` of the request to conform to Customer AND Address

```
Type 'Customer | Address' is not assignable to type 'Customer & Address'.
  Type 'Customer' is not assignable to type 'Customer & Address'.
    Property 'firstLine' is missing in type 'Customer' but required in type 'Address'.(2322)
input.tsx(11, 5): 'firstLine' is declared here.
```

Please note that despite the similar wording of the title of the issue [Infer the type value of a property based on the type value of another property in an array of object in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74722005/infer-the-type-value-of-a-property-based-on-the-type-value-of-another-property-i), the scenario and outcome are very different.

Update:
[Playground 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=2&pln=35&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJQCbWQbwFDKHIICuAzmAPYC20AXMgMLlW1TIA%20yIJANrwBoCROBgxQIZMgwCCYiVLwBfPHlCRYiFMwo1s%20Itzi0GFKKADmy1eujwkyOeMllcwwjGBQKAGVARTMHMQKxU1cDstNExoAFUABww4SAAlCABHEkkwAFk4ePjLN0NSXTYGHVZoIUNRZylZeRdrcI17FHQsKASk1IysigAeAGlkCAAPSBAMVwBrCABPShhorp7kiDTM7LyCywA%20YqJ5hYZhmqIANzheLIZOuMSNrYHc-MKQgG1hgF0WhEoIAoyEoMW8yAAvMhPj9kHBXA8oDDVACgWBkNQFgAVAAWRShOFKVSgDBwIGMAWQAHIAEaUGlUpQCOFNBq4TzeMB%20ECUqmY5BmCAQMCMpRwhFg1SgrpkAB08XIOIAFJjcZYAJQowHAkhPSBYhbxFBQqlEvRQKlatHIXW9Tb9bKQ3AnOimljmqnM5DXW6UskU5AMKkAETglwgovFq0edpe2UGYENEGWNr1EANRv2eGl0DInwADD9Prbng6KJ8qScqT9YVCS31tuWqT6stXVDASCAEGBgIDU3bEUqXcgTinEesG69dh8LMyW5Tx2m4xRp5ZPicfuqjoQc94C0WN0758ogA)
[Solution Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJQCbWQbwFDKHIICuAzmAPYC20AXMgMLlW1TIA%20yIJANrwBoCROBgxQIZMgwCCYiVLwBfPHlCRYiFMwo1s%20Itzi0GFKKADmy1eujwkyOeMllcwwjGBQKAGVARTMHMQKxU1cDstNExoAFUABww4SAAlCABHEkkwAFk4ePjLN0NSXTYGHVZoIUNRZylZeRdrcI17FHQsKASk1IysigAeAGlkCAAPSBAMVwBrCABPShhorp7kiDTM7LyCywA%20YqJ5hYZhmqIANzheLIZOuMSNrYHc-MKQgG1hgF0WhEoIAoyEoMW8yAAvMhPj9kHBXA8oDDVACgWBkNQFgAVAAWRShOFKVSgDBwIGMAWQAHIAEaUGlUpQCOFNBq4TzeMB%20ECUqmY5BmCAQMCMpRwhFg1SgrpkAB08XIOIAFJjcZYAJQowHAkhPSBYhbxFBQqlEvRQKlatHIXW9Tb9bKQ3AnOimljmqnM5DXW6UskU5AMKkAETglwgovFq0edpe2UGYENEGWNr1EANRv2eGl0DInwADD9Prbng6KJ8qScqT9YVCS31tuWqT6stXVDASCAEGBgIDU3bEcgRmNJhBpnNFinEesG69dh8LMh9kqXchzt6bndo9003GKPPLN8fuqjoQc94C0WTrWN77lEA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateRequest` is of type `OrderUpdateRequest`, so from there TypeScirpt will always think that the value of the `key` property of `updateRequest` will be either `"customer" | "address"`

If you want to be able to specify that `updateRequest.key` is `"customer"`, you would need to add a generic type on `OrderUpdateRequest`

```
interface OrderUpdateRequest<T extends "customer" | "address"> {
    key: T,
    value: T extends "customer" ?  Customer : Address
}

const myThing = {customer: {name: 'Bob'}, address: {firstLine: 'my street'}} as Order

const updateRequest = {key:'customer',  value: {name : 'Dave'}} as OrderUpdateRequest<"customer">
myThing[updateRequest.key] = updateRequest['value']
```

This example is really simple and can be improve if you want to add other possible keys, but it is just to show my point :

Once a value is typed, TypeScript will only identify the value with its type, no matter how the type was construct. So to be able to have a different behavior depending on the value of a property, you should use generic typing

If you want to use more than two keys you can use a mapping interface to associate each key with a specific type, and then using the key of your interface in you generic types

```
interface OrderUpdateRequestMapping {
    customer: Customer,
    address: Address
}

interface OrderUpdateRequest<K extends keyof OrderUpdateRequestMapping> {
    key: K,
    value: OrderUpdateRequestMapping[K]
}
```

Comment: Hi Florent, thanks for your response. My example only has two properties but in reality would have many more, so the ternary expression `T extends "customer" ?  Customer : Address` wouldn't work for that use case. Is there a way to make the value type work more dynamically, such as some kind of map?

Similar issue with `<T extends "customer" | "address">` part...could the list of available keys be passed in as a variable?

Comment: Oh yes it is totally possible, i've updated my answer :)

Comment: Exellent! That completely fits my use case, thank you so much for you help :)

Comment: If I call a function which makes a request to update the order, how can I type the parameters to make sure there is no compilation error?

In the TS playground link in the bottom of my question (link too long for comments), I thought I could do `key: keyof OrderUpdateRequestMapping, value: OrderUpdateRequestMapping[key]`  but key cannot be used as an index

Comment: DW, I answered my own question :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to create a function that returns a object of type `UpdateRequest<K, V>` and then providing overloads for that function:

```js
// add more possible key type combinations here
type UpdateValue = Customer | Address;
type UpdateKey = "customer" | "address";

type Customer = { name: string };
type Address = { firstLine: string };

// use generics to make the type more broadly applicable
interface UpdateRequest<K extends UpdateKey, V extends UpdateValue> {
  key: K;
  value: V;
}

// function overloads 
export function createUpdate(
  key: "customer",
  value: Customer,
): UpdateRequest<"customer", Customer>;

export function createUpdate(
  key: "address",
  value: Address,
): UpdateRequest<"address", Address>;

// function implementation
export function createUpdate<
  K extends UpdateKey,
  V extends UpdateValue,
>(key: K, value: UpdateValue) {
  return { key, value } as UpdateRequest<K, V>;
}
```

Personally I prefer this approach due to the added flexibility that is provided, like the absence of a ternary statement. This is what the above code will result in:

```
// returns -> UpdateRequest<"address", Address>
const x = createUpdate("address", { firstLine: "123" });

// returns -> UpdateRequest<"customer", Customer>
const y = createUpdate("customer", { name: "John" });
```